# How to query data from table1 where table1_id not in table2 and table1_id not in table 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've 3 tables in database `dishes`, `price_deals` and `give_away_deals`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: dishes
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime

# Table name: price_deals
#
#  id              :integer         not null, primary key
#  name            :string(255)
#  dish_id         :integer
#  created_at      :datetime
#  updated_at      :datetime

# Table name: give_away_deals
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  dish_id     :integer
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
```

I've to get the `id` and `name` from `dishes` table. Where id not in `price_deals` and id not in `give_away_deals` without duplicate id.

Suppose I've 10 records in `dishes` table `id` 1 to 10.

In `price_deals` table `dish_id` are `2,4,5`.

In `give_away_deals` table `dish_id` are `1,3,6`

## Expected result:

Then, I've to get the `id` and `name` from `dishes` table where `id` are `7,8,9,10`

I tried this query,

```
Dish.all(:select => "id, name", :conditions => ["id not in (select dish_id from price_deals)", "id not in (select dish_id from give_away_deals)"])
```

But it returns only data which is not in `price_deals`.

What's wrong in the above query and how to get the expected result?

This is the SQL query I got in rails server

```
SELECT id, name FROM "dishes" WHERE (id not in (select dish_id from price_deals))
```

Comment: Could you put some SQL generated by Rails?

Comment: I added the SQL generated by Rails in the question...

Comment: Change `"id not in (select dish_id from price_deals)", "id not in (select dish_id from give_away_deals)"` in `"id not in (select dish_id from price_deals) and id not in (select dish_id from give_away_deals)"`

Comment: SyntaxError: (irb):245: syntax error, unexpected keyword_and, expecting ']'
...h_id from give_away_deals)" and "id not in (select dish_id f...
...                               ^
(irb):245: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting $end
...ect dish_id from price_deals)"])
...                               ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK time to some bigger answer.

Try this code:

```
first = PriceDeal.select(:dish_id).map(&:dish_id)
second = GiveAwayDeal.select(:dish_id).map(&:dish_id)
Dish.select('id, name').where("id not IN(?)", (first + second).uniq)
```

I think that should generate a good one SQL query

Comment: 1.9.2p290 :281 >   first = PriceDeal.select(:dish_id)
 => [#<PriceDeal dish_id: 2>, #<PriceDeal dish_id: 5>] 
1.9.2p290 :282 > second = GiveAwayDeal.select(:dish_id)
 => [#<GiveAwayDeal dish_id: 6>] 
1.9.2p290 :283 > Dish.where("id not IN(?) and id not IN(?)", first, second)
 => []

Comment: SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT("price_deals"."dish_id") FROM "price_deals"
  PriceDeal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT dish_id FROM "price_deals"
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT("give_away_deals"."dish_id") FROM "give_away_deals"
  GiveAwayDeal Load (0.1ms)  SELECT dish_id FROM "give_away_deals"
Rendered price_deals/_deallinks.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Dish Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "dishes".* FROM "dishes" WHERE (id not IN(NULL,NULL) and id not IN(NULL))

Comment: I add `.map(&:dish_id)` in first and second line. Is it change anything?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
Dish.includes(:price_deal, :give_away_deal).where("price_deals.id is null and give_away_deals.id is null")
```

methods `includes` and `where` works together with one query

```
SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT `dishes`.`id` AS t0_r0, `dishes`.`name` AS t0_r1, `dishes`.`created_at` AS t0_r2, `dishes`.`updated_at` AS t0_r3, `price_deals`.`id` AS t1_r0, `price_deals`.`dish_id` AS t1_r1, `price_deals`.`created_at` AS t1_r2, `price_deals`.`updated_at` AS t1_r3, `give_away_deals`.`id` AS t2_r0, `give_away_deals`.`dish_id` AS t2_r1, `give_away_deals`.`created_at` AS t2_r2, `give_away_deals`.`updated_at` AS t2_r3 FROM `dishes` LEFT OUTER JOIN `price_deals` ON `price_deals`.`dish_id` = `dishes`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `give_away_deals` ON `give_away_deals`.`dish_id` = `dishes`.`id` WHERE (price_deals.id is null and give_away_deals.id is null)
```

I use Rails 3.2.1 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: The code works but I need only id and name. Thanks tastesDiffer